# How to set status code 404 when returning empty IAsyncEnumerable<T> in ASP.NET Core (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a controller action that returns an IAsyncEnumerable.  It queries a data source and if data is available, each result is "yield return"-ed (serialized by System.Text.Json and returned to client).  But how can I set Status Code to 404 if no results are available?  Right now, if no results are available, the method returns an empty JSON array with Status Code = 200.

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
{
    IEnumerable<string> stringResults = await myData.GetStringsAsync();

    if (stringResults is object && stringResults.Any())
    {
        foreach (string result in stringResults)
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound(); //CS1622: Cannot return a value from an iterator....
    }
}
```

**Update**

I want this streaming to the client as soon as results are available. If I return `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`, then the whole list/array/collection must be complete before handing off to *System.Text.Json* for serialization. I don't think this is very memory-efficient.

Comment: @TheGeneral if it's null?

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` won't make a synchronous method async. Why are you using it?

Comment: I want this streaming to the client as soon as results are available.  If I return Task<IEnumerable<string>>, then the whole list/array/collection must be complete before handing off to System.Text.Json for serialization.  I don't think this is very memory-efficient.

Comment: `async Task<IActionResult> GetStrings() ... return Ok(stringResults);` however, calling `.Any()` will cause the collection to be enumerated twice.

Comment: For everyone else, this is only supported in core 6 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/iasyncenumerable-not-buffered-by-mvc

Comment: ".Any() will cause the collection to be enumerated twice" - Are you sure about this?  Why would the collection be enumerated if I'm just checking for emptiness?

Comment: if I try ... else { Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound; } then I get InvalidOperationException "StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started."

Comment: This question is nonsensical. You need to know whether the enumerable is empty or not to determine whether to return 200 or 404, and the only way you can know if an enumerable is empty or not... *is to enumerate it*. Which entirely defeats the purpose of using `IAsyncEnumerable`!

Comment: If `await myData.GetStringsAsync` returns `IEnumerable`, is it really returning a `List`? In which case you already have all the results? Or does that method stream the results synchronously?

Comment: I guess technically, it does.  But if I stream the results, the TTFB is much quicker and I don't have to keep the client waiting as long.  And I also wanted to be able to inspect the List for emptiness so I can set StatusCode to 404.

After reading David Fowler's explanation here (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35364) I'm not sure it's possible to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix an async generator and an mvc action that returns `NotFound()`. But you can write two methods.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStrings()
{
    IEnumerable<string> stringResults = await myData.GetStringsAsync();
    if (stringResults == null)
        return NotFound();
    var e = stringResults.GetEnumerator();
    if (!e.MoveNext())
        return NotFound();
    return Ok(AsEnum(e));

    async IAsyncEnumerable<string> AsEnum(IEnumerator<string> e){
        do {
            yield return e.Current;
        } while (e.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

With any extra error handling & disposing the enumerator.

However there is still a difference in behaviour here. Unlike an `async Task` method, `IEnumerable` & `IAsyncEnumerable` generator methods do not start until the first call to `.MoveNext[Async]`.

As your previous implementation would return an `IAsyncEnumerable` to MVC before executing any of your action. HTTP headers would be written and the json serialiser would call `IAsyncEnumerable.MoveNextAsync`, before your `GetStringAsync` service is even called.

If you want to wait for the first result before returning 200 / 404, then you have to wait for the backend service to return something before you can write any HTTP headers.

Using time to first byte as a metric here is completely misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, this still results in a delayed TTFB (i.e., not streaming).  Also I think you meant IActionResult instead of IAsyncResult.  So it looks like if I want to be able to set StatusCode, then I won't be able to stream.

Comment: As we were saying, if your source data isn't actually streaming, you might not notice if the output is actually streamed. Is the response transport encoding chunked? While your previous example may have started the response headers and "[" immediately, before you could tell if the results were empty. The actual results would have been written in a similar time. So your TTFB may be misleading.